# React Native Touch ID

Tags: react-native

I was using this [library](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id) for touch id / face id authentication. Is there any way I can get the event when the user starts placing finger on the touch id sensor? The library seems to be good but I didn't find much that solves my problem. All I can do now is to authenticate the user and get the result ( either error or success ) on the fly.

Thank You

Comment: i think all those events happen outside of your application

Comment: Why do you need such events?

Comment: To do some animations